# Android resize the bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, imageview

I want the `bitmap` to be re-sized to 600*600 after it's selected and inserted in the `imageview`

this is code for the imageview of the bitmap

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
chosenBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
imageView.setBackgroundColor(0);
imageView.setImageBitmap(chosenBitmap);
```

Comment: Do you want it resized and saved or resized inside the imageview itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Bitmap bMap =   Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(chosenBitmap, 600, 600, true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

For more information look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)